# Different First Page in a document using microsoft office interop word in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office, office-interop

How can i create a different first page header and footer in a document using Microsoft.office.interop.word.

I have tried the following code but only in the first page, header and footer is coming.
I want it in the other way(first page shouldn't have header and footer). 
can any one Please help me ? i tried a lot.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application w = new icrosoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
 w.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1;
 doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
 doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("HEader Text");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application w = new icrosoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
 doc = w.ActiveDocument;
 doc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1;

 // Setting Different First page Header & Footer
 doc.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.Text = "First Page Header";
 doc.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.Text = "First Page Footer";

 // Setting Other page Header & Footer
 doc.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text = "Other Page Header";
 doc.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text = "Other Page Footer";
```