# Adding picture in header on every page except the first

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am generating a Word document from C# using Micorosft Word Interop.

I want to insert some images into the header on every page. I can successfully do it on every page with the following code:

```
string imgHeader1 = "C:/image1.jpg";
foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
{
    HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
    header.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 96;
    header.Shapes.AddPicture(imgHeader1, 0, 1, 0, -40, 120, 20);
}
```

Now I want to do the same, but NOT on the first page. 
My suggestion was the following:

```
document.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1; //True 

string imgHeader1 = "C:/image1.jpg";
foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
{
    HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
    //wdHeaderFooterFirstPage would be for first page..
    header.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 96;
    header.Shapes.AddPicture(imgHeader1, 0, 1, 0, -40, 120, 20);
}
```

The problem is that the image is still appearing on the first page instead of the second.

If I look at the answer from this question [Different First Page in a document using microsoft office interop word in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655387/diffrent-first-page-in-a-document-using-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-c-sharp) and copy the code into my project the text is appearing on the right headers, but it does not seem to work with images(?)

Comment: TRy setting DifferentFirstPage for every section in your loop, since the document apparently has more than one Section. DifferentFirstPage can be set by section...

Comment: that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the InlineShapes object and apply the resizing and positiong after did the trick for me.

```
Shape shape = header.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgHeader1, 0, 1, header.Range).ConvertToShape();
shape.Left = -1;
shape.Top = -42;
shape.Width = 275;
shape.Height = 151;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me. I set DifferentFirstPage for every section in the document, apply the formatting, insert some test text, insert the image. (Note that I have a `using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in my solution, thus objects from the Word object model are prefaced with `Word.`)

```
string imgHeader1 = "C:/image1.jpg";
foreach (Word.Section section in document.Sections)
{
    section.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1;
    Word.HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
    //wdHeaderFooterFirstPage would be for first page..
    header.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 96;
    header.Range.Text = "test";
    header.Shapes.AddPicture(imgHeader1, 0, 1, 0, -40, 120, 20);
}
```

Comment: for me the image is still appearing on the first page

Comment: Then there may be a problem with how the document is structured - where the section breaks are. Are you certain this "first page" is actually the first page of a section? And by "section" I mean a *NEW PAGE* section break? Or has a "continuous" section break been used that's on this page? In that case, Word will *not* see it as the first page of the new section, but as the last page of the previous section.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use something like check if its the first page. If true then do nothing else use that image