# Create Word File Using Microsoft.office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am using this code to create Word file Programmatically using Microsoft.interop.word C#, when I create it , I have aproblem that it is repeat the header of the First page to all of pages of the Documents, How I can set it to put the header for the first Page of the Document only?

and that's my code :

```
 public void create_Document()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create an instance for word app
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            //Set animation status for word application
            winword.ShowAnimation = false;

            //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
            winword.Visible = false;

            //Create a missing variable for missing value
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //Create a new document
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            //Add header into the document
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in document.Sections)
            {
                //Get the header range and add the header details.
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
                headerRange.Font.Size = 30;
                headerRange.Text = "Exam Dates for the " + course_name;
                section.Borders.Enable = 1;
                section.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
                section.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth300pt;
                section.Borders.OutsideColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack;

            }



            //adding text to document
            document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
            // document.Content.Text = "Exam Dates :" + Environment.NewLine;

            //Add paragraph with Heading 1 style
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
            object styleHeading1 = "Heading 1";
            para1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading1);
            para1.Range.Text = "Exam Dates";
            para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();



            //Create a 5X5 table and insert some dummy record
            // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 4,2, ref missing, ref missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 1, 2, ref missing, ref missing);

            firstTable.Borders.Enable = 1;

            firstTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Exam Name";
            firstTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Exam Date";
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ExamName,Date from Exam where CourseNum='" + course_number + "'", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int intRow = 2;

            // Retrieve the data and insert into new rows.
            Object beforeRow = Type.Missing;
            string[] dates;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dates = reader[1].ToString().Split(' ');
                firstTable.Rows.Add(ref beforeRow);
                firstTable.Cell(intRow, 1).Range.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                firstTable.Cell(intRow, 2).Range.Text = dates[0];

                intRow += 1;
            }
            //Save the document
            object filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Attachments\\Exams.docx";
           document.SaveAs2(ref filename);

           // document.Save();
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)document).Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)winword).Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
 }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }


        }//create document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the other `wdHeaderFooterIndex` property `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` is the one you are looking for. Thanks to @Arun’s answer at [Different First Page in a document using microsoft office interop word in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655387/different-first-page-in-a-document-using-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-c-shar)... You will see you need to also set the documents `PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter` value to -1.

Simply add the first line below to the code and change the second line in the code to get the header range for the first page only.

```
document.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = -1;  // <-- add this line
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
//Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
```

This should get the header to appear only on the first page of each section. Hope this helps.